# SQL Server: Conditional Statement Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements, qsqlquery

I would like to calculate the actual working time(s) by deducting the break time within the Work Start Time and Work End Time.

What I have:

```
•Work Start Time (10:10:00)
•Work End Time (14:10:00)
•Break 1 Start Time (10:00:00)
•Break 1 End Time (10:15:00)
•Break 2 Start Time (14:00:00)
•Break 2 End Time (14:30:00)
•Break 3 Start Time (17:45:00)
•Break 3 End Time (18:00:00)
```

But there are many conditions such as:

- Work Start Time might start before Break 1 Start Time, then Work End Time end before Break 1 End Time
- Work Start Time might start before Break 1 Start Time, then Work End Time end before Break 2 Start Time
- Work Start Time might start before Break 2 Start Time but after Break 1 End Time, then Work End Time end before Break 3 End Time

And so on.

There are so many possibilities if I write the `If-Else` statement to check.

May I know is there any smarter or simpler way to check and calculate the actual working time?

Comment: There are 3 fixed break time? Please add some sample data.

Comment: Hi I have edited my question with some sample data.

Comment: What have you tried till now? It would help if you add a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to tell without your sample input/output but still basic query would be:

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b9efd5ddec7c5e3b47fd882e66120a0)

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, 
          DATEDIFF(minute, Work Start Time, Work End Time) - 
          (
              DATEDIFF(minute, Break 1 Start Time, Break 1 End Time) + 
              DATEDIFF(minute, Break 2 Start Time, Break 2 End Time) + 
              DATEDIFF(minute, Break 3 Start Time, Break 3 End Time)
          ), 0), 114) 


/* Results: 03:00 */
```

Updated based on conditionally

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Break 1 Start Time > Work Start Time THEN
                  CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, Work Start Time, Work End Time) - (DATEDIFF(minute, Break 1 Start Time, Break 1 End Time) + DATEDIFF(minute, Break 2 Start Time, Break 2 End Time) +               DATEDIFF(minute, Break 3 Start Time, Break 3 End Time)), 0), 114) 
            WHEN  Break 2 Start Time > Work Start Time AND Break 1 END Time > Work Start Time AND  THEN 
                  CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, Work Start Time, Work End Time) - (DATEDIFF(minute, Break 2 Start Time, Break 2 End Time) +               DATEDIFF(minute, Break 3 Start Time, Break 3 End Time)), 0), 114) 
            WHEN  Break 3 Start Time > Work Start Time AND Break 2 END Time > Work Start Time AND  THEN 
                  CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, Work Start Time, Work End Time) - (DATEDIFF(minute, Break 3 Start Time, Break 3 End Time)), 0), 114) 
            ELSE '00:00' END AS [Working Hours]    



/* Results: 03:00 */
```

Comment: Your query only can calculate if my Work Start Time is before Break 1 Start and Work End Time is after Break 3 End. How about if Work Start Time is before Break 2 Start and Work End Time is before Break 3 Start ?

Comment: No. It wont bother about `Break 1 Start` and `Work End Time`, it will just sum all the break time and deduct from the working hours. You can check the mentioned case here [FIDDLE DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=682732a4678f4d4441585b47a5fb84bb)

Comment: I mean it doesn't work if the working time is not covering whole day. Your query is sum all 3 break time duration and minus them off from the working hour. But how if the working time start from 10:45:00(after break 1 ended)?

Comment: I can see your queries are only checking with the work start time. It cannot determine how many breaks are between the work start time and work end time. Thus how can it calculate the actual working time?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to the problem:

```
select sum(TimeInCurrentEvent) -- in minutes
from (
  select
   sum(case when EventType = 'Work Start Time' then 1 
        when EventType = 'Work End Time' then -1 end) over (order by TimeOfDay) as InWorkSpan
   ,sum(case when EventType = 'Break Start Time' then 1 
        when EventType = 'Break End Time' then -1 end) over (order by TimeOfDay) as InBreakSpan
   ,datediff(minute, TimeOfDay, Lead(TimeOfDay, 1, null) over (order by TimeOfDay)) as TimeInCurrentEvent
   ,*
   from WorkEvents
) a
where InWorkSpan = 1 and InBreakSpan = 0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5f345/12

The biggest trick I used here was the two `sum(...) over(...)` lines. The first one will return a 1 if the current event is a "Work Start" or is before the next "Work End" and 0 otherwise. The second is similar, except it tracks breaks instead. Using those two values, we can filter to the set of events that are in between work start and end, but outside of break starts and ends using the `where` clause at the end.

After that, the only thing left is determining the amount of time spent between each event. To do that I used a `lead(...) over (...)` to pull the next's events time to the previous line in order to compare. Summing the rows that we filtered down to will get you only time that was spent inside of work and outside of breaks.

If you're looking for more understanding on how this query works, I would suggest running only the subquery to see what the windowing functions are returning.

Note that some invalid data (having two Work End Times in a row or starting out with a Work End Time) would cause the sum's described above to not return 0 or 1 and make handling this problem a lot harder - that wasn't described in your question so I hope that it's not an issue! This code is also extensible to situations like grouping by a user id or by date by using a `partition by` statement in the `over` clauses.

Comment: Hi sjager, I really appreciate your effort. I spent some time to understand your query and explanation. But I can't really understand the logic in your query. I try to run it but I'm not sure what to put for eventType. My table only contains: Department (HR, IT), shift(day or night), start date,end date(effective day for work time table), break1, break1 duration ... break 3 duration. I need to determine my break N end time by adding break N duration to break N. I really appreciate if you can spend some time to help to check it out.